# How to construct a railway tree and find the shortest way between two destinations?

Tags: python, algorithm, tree

I'm trying to put a set of cities into a Python tree, but I haven't found the easiest method to do it.

I've built two trees that have one city in common.
Here are my trees:

[As you see, Milan is the common city between both of them.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7u9wS.png)

I tried to use this code:

```
class Foret:

    def __init__(self,item) : 
        self.info = item
        self.child = None 
        self.brother = None

    def getRootVal(self,) :
        return self.info

    def setRootVal(self,item) : 
        self.info = item

    def getChild(self) :
       return self.child

    def getBrother(self): 
       return self.brother

    def modifyChild(self,newNode):
       self.child = Foret(newNode)

    def modifyBrother(self,newNode): 
       self.brother = Foret(newNode)
```

How can I transform the trees in the picture into Python trees?

Comment: There's nothing obviously wrong with what you're doing, except that some of the nodes need to have 2 children and some need to have 3 children. You could allow your nodes to have arrays of children, or have three children allowing some to be null, depending on your needs. Could you explain specifically why what you're doing isn't working?

Comment: The tree in the picture must be in some kind of file or data structure. In order to answer your question, we need to know exactly the format of the source data.

Comment: Jared Windover- Can you give me an example please, because I don't know how to do that . Thank you

Comment: Because if I put this for example instead of info child and brother,  `self.info = info /n self.children = []`